# fill up cities from Postgresql similar to kayak.com

Tags: postgresql

How can I fill up cities as typing in similar to how is done in kayak.com taking the data from postgresql?

So, If I type in the letters Ma  All the cities starting by MA show up

Thank you so much

Comment: You really need to provide more details, unless you are just asking about the SQL query, in which case see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL query like this one should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name LIKE "Ma%";
```

- `cities` is the table that contains your cities
- `name` is the column in that table that stores the city's name

There's a newer operator [`SIMILAR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) that you can use instead of `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build an autocomplete pulldown menu like you see on kayak.com you need a front-end and back-end component.

For the front end you can use [JQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#options) or one of the many available libraries out there like this [one](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html). Of course you can also build your own.

In all cases, though, you'll need a datasource to populate the pulldown. Since your question referred to Postgresql, I'll assume you already have a table with potential location names and know how to query it (as @Philippe A shows in his answer).

What you need to do query the back-end (via AJAX) to retrieve this information. This can be done repeatedly as the user types after, say, at least 3 characters have been typed. Or, it can be done once and the data stored in a Javascript variable your code searches.

Since you didn't specify the programming language you're using the back-end it's hard to provide example code but, at least for the front end, take a look at this JQuery UI [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)